# Error encoding model [App\Post] with ID [1] to JSON: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Tags: php, laravel

i'm a complete beginner to laravel. I have no idea what the error is. can enyone help me to fix this?

this is my code for retriving data from databse.

```
<div class="card-body">
         <h3><a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}">{{$post->title}}</a></h3><br>
         <p>Type : {{$post->type}}</p>
         <p>Created at {{$post->created_at}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is where the issue lies? There's no json attempts here. If you remove this block, do you still get the same error? If not, add each part in one line at a time and see which one is triggering it.

Comment: The error most likely does not lie in this code. You can double-check by looking the source in the browser to make sure the link looks correct. Post the function for the route for `/posts/{id}`, the issue lies somewhere in there.

Comment: Then post the code for `PostsController@show`. If there is more to the error message, such as a line number or trace, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: i created a route. Route::get('/home/posts/{id}', 'PostsController@show')->with('id',$id);  now it says "Undefined variable: id"

Comment: Remove the `with` on the route, it's not needed.

Comment: did it. again the previous error is comming. (error on the topic)

Comment: i think the error is comming from this code.                                   
 public static function forModel($model, $message)
    {
        return new static('Error encoding model ['.get_class($model).'] with ID ['.$model->getKey().'] to JSON: '.$message);
    }